# How to collect Kubernetes cluster logs (api server, scheduler, autoscaler)?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, fluentd

How can I collect Kubernetes Cluster Logs like API Server Logs, Auto-Scaler logs, Scheduler Logs?

I use fluentD to collect application logs, Can I use that to also collect the cluster logs? Which file in the nodes have the cluster logs?

Answer (score 0):

`api-server`, `auto-scaler` and `scheduler` are containers and write log to console. You can use `filebeat` to collect logs from there.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned azure-aks, AKS is a managed Kubernetes service such that you have access to just the Kubernetes API endpoint. You don’t get to see the kube-apiserver, controller-manager, and scheduler pods. To see logs you have to use  Azure Diagnostics Logs.